# Finding proper conditions for constants in which $f$ is harmonic(Adams 12.4)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I hope this one is not a duplicate. I'm asked to find the condition for the constants $a,b,c$ to ensure $f(ax+by, cz)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

What I am thinking is to get $u=ax+by,~ v=cz$ and assume $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ so I can find that certain conditions for constants. I found
$$a^2f_{uu}+b^2f_{uu}+c^2f_{vv}=0$$

Am I on a\the right track? Thanks

Comment: What is known about $f\>$, apart from sufficient differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given, that $f$ is harmonic, I assume, that is 
$$ \Delta f =\partial_u^2 f + \partial_v^2 f = 0$$
we have
\begin{align*}
  \partial_x^2  \bigl(f(ax+by, cz)\bigr) &= a^2 \partial_u^2 f(ax+by, cz)\\
  \partial_y^2  \bigl(f(ax+by, cz)\bigr) &= b^2 \partial_u^2 f(ax+by, cz)\\
  \partial_z^2  \bigl(f(ax+by, cz)\bigr) &= c^2 \partial_v^2 f(ax+by, cz)\\
\end{align*}
Hence, as you wrote, we want
$$ \Delta\bigl(f(ax+by,cz)\bigr) = \bigl((a^2 + b^2)\partial_u^2 f + c^2 \partial_v^2 f\bigr)(ax+by, cz) $$
Now, as $\partial_v^2 f = -\partial_u^2 f$, as $f$ is harmonic, this equals 
$$ (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)\partial_u^2 f(ax+by, cz) $$
which is, in general, equal to zero only if 
$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$